# Why is this pointer not being assigned to a new object?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm defining a binary search tree class like this:

```
template <class T>
class BSTNode
{
  public:
    BSTNode(){
      right = left = 0;
    }

    BSTNode(const T& el, BSTNode * l = 0, BSTNode * r = 0)
    {
    val = el; left = l; right = r;
    }   

    T val;
    BSTNode * right;
    BSTNode * left;
};

template <class T>
class BST
{
  public:
    BST(){ root = 0;}           
    void Insert(const T& el);
  private:
    BSTNode<T> * root;
};
```

and I implement the `Insert()` function like this:

```
template <class T>
void BST<T>::Insert(const T& el)
{
  bool bEqual = false;
  BSTNode<T> * p = root;

  while(p)
  {
    if(el == p->val)
    {
      bEqual = true;
      return;
    }
    if(el < p->val)
    {
      // go left
      p = p->left;
    }
    if(el > p->val)
    {
      // go right
      p = p->right;
    }
  }

  if(!p)
  {
    std::cout << "creating new node " << el << "\n";
    p = new BSTNode<T>(el);
  }  
}
```

Why does the `root` pointer variable stay at 0, and not the address of the new object?

Comment: You don't do `root = ?;` anywhere, why would it ever change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never do `root = ?;` in your code; also, `p = new BSTNode<T>(el);` leaks memory.

My guess is that you wanted to `p` to be a reference to pointer, so you could change the original pointer.

```
 BSTNode<T> *& p = root; // watch out, it won't solve anything
```

But, in such case, `p` is not-reassignable. You may want to check if pointer you assign to `p` is null and just insert the new value in correct place (eg. `p->left = new BSTNode<T>(el);`) and reassign `p` only when given pointer is not null.

I mean:

```
template <class T>
void BST<T>::Insert(const T& el)
{
  bool bEqual = false;
  BSTNode<T> * p = root;

  if (p == 0)
  {
     root = new BSTNode<T>(el);
     return;
  }

  while(true)
  {
    if(el == p->val)
    {
      bEqual = true;
      return;
    }
    if(el < p->val)
    {
      if (p->left == 0)
      {
        p->left = new BSTNode<T>(el);
        return;
      }
      p = p->left;
    }
    if(el > p->val)
    {
      if (p->right == 0)
      {
        p->right = new BSTNode<T>(el);
        return;
      }
      p = p->right;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: no I never intended `p` to be a reference to a pointer actually. But what do you mean by "Watch out, it won't solve anything."? Are you saying that because the reference `p` has been instantiated to `root` and is not reassignable?

Comment: @BeeBand, your original code assumed that when you do `p = p->left; p = new BSTNode<T>(el);`, then original's `p`'s `left` will also be changed; that functionality is functionality of reference, so your code was assuming that the pointer is actually a reference to the pointer. For the second part of your question: yes; you cannot do `BSTNode<T> *& p = root; p = p->left;`, because you cannot reassign a reference. To have the original algorithm working, you would've to use pointer to pointer - I personally prefer my way.

Answer (score 1):

Because at the construction of object

the statement

```
  p= root
```

initializes p as a null pointer..

You create a new object and pass its address to p instead of root...

The thing is p is just a copy of root and not a reference to this pointer..